# Issue creating variable in R

Tags: r

I have just started to learn R and I am trying to create a new variable + using ifelse.

```
   nlsy$ethnicity <- as.factor(ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Black", "Black",
  ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Hispanic", "Hispanic",
  ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Non-Black / Non-Hispanic" & nlsy$race_ethnicity="White", "White", "Other"))))
```

Comment: Use `case_when` from `dplyr` to avoid nested `ifelse` statements, but it would also be good to see some sample data to better understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: What exactly is the issue in the code that you have tried here?

Comment: I get the error:    Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Hispanic", "Hispanic",
    ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Non-Black / Non-Hispanic" & nlsy$race="

Comment: That is because you have last condition as `nlsy$race_ethnicity="White"`, which actually should be `nlsy$race_ethnicity== "White"`. Also maybe the condition should be `|` (OR) rather than `&` (AND).

Comment: I believe Ronak is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case_when` from the `dplyr` package here:

```r
nlsy$ethnicity <- case_when(
    nlsy$race_ethnicity == "Black" ~ "Black",
    nlsy$race_ethnicity == "Hispanic" ~ "Hispanic",
    nlsy$race_ethnicity == "Non-Black / Non-Hispanic" | nlsy$race_ethnicity == "White" ~ "White",
    TRUE ~ "Other
)
```

Using `case_when` is often preferable to `ifelse` especially in the case where the latter involves many nested calls.

Answer (score 1):

We could make this a bit more simpler with

```
library(dplyr)
nlsy <- nlsy %>%
     mutate(ethnicity = replace(replace(race_ethnicity, 
      race_ethnicity == "Non-Black / Non-Hispanic", "White"), 
        !race_ethnicity %in% c("Black", "Hispanic", "White"), "Other"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package called [fmtr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=fmtr) that is good for this situation.  It has a `value()` function, which is similar to a SAS user-defined format.  Here is how you use it:

```
library(fmtr)

# Define format
fmt <- value(condition(x == "Black", "Black"),
             condition(x == "Hispanic", "Hispanic"),
             condition(x == "Non-Black / Non-Hispanic" & x == "White", "White"),
             condition(TRUE, "Other")

# Apply format      
nlsy$ethnicity <- fapply(nlsy$race_ethnicity, fmt)
```